# ASP Net File Upload

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am trying to read the file content from FileUpload control the following way

```
BinaryReader b = new BinaryReader(FileUpload1.PostedFile.InputStream);
byte[] binData = b.ReadBytes(FileUpload1.PostedFile.ContentLength);
```

I do not want to save the file to server, instead I wanted to get Byte array and
store it in database.

By doing the above it not only reads the contents of the file, but it also appends the html of the posted page. How do I get only the contents from the file.

Comment: You haven't posted any code which would "append the HTML of the posted page".

Comment: I am not appending the html. I store the binData in the database. Then I downloaded the file the database. The downloaded file has my file content and then below it html of the page.

Comment: Please post the **rendered** HTML of the `<form>` element. Are you using the correct `enctype` value?

Comment: No. Can you explain how to use the correct enctype.

Comment: Please post the rendered HTML first.

Comment: Earlier I Had the following code. It worked with the VS environment but when deployed it gives exception unable to find the file c:\test\sample.txt. So I tried with inputstream fileName = FileUpload1.PostFile.FileName;

 System.IO.FileStream _FileStream = new System.IO.FileStream(fileName,                    System.IO.FileMode.Open, System.IO.FileAccess.Read);
_BinaryReader = new System.IO.BinaryReader(_FileStream);

 buffer = _BinaryReader.ReadBytes((Int32)_TotalBytes);

SaveDocumentToDatabase(Id, buffer)

Comment: The enctype I have on page load                                          this.Page.Form.Enctype = "multipart/form-data";

Comment: When you rendered HTML what are you referring to Is the source view of the html page or the document that was downloaded

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to use [FileBytes](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.fileupload.filebytes(v=vs.110).aspx) property?

Comment: No. I used ReadBytes. Is there going to be a difference. The odd thing is I tested pdf,xls,docx and jpg documents as well. It only happens
whenever I read the buffer content of txt file it appends the posted html document . This is happening in Dev Environment. I am not sure if it will work in a deployed environment.